# Check ASP.NET MVC values (roles) from client (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app that is basically one page with a bunch of AJAX calls that parse returned JSON and then using jQuery will populate the page.  So, for example, if I call `/API/Users/List` it will return some JSON and then I'll parse that and dynamically create an `li` element for each user.  Then, I put an `edit` link next to each user name and hook it up to do the necessary editing (jQuery with another AJAX call).

What I'm curious about is how I would go about showing/hiding the `edit` link based upon role.  I have a strongly typed view and can populate hidden fields with user info (`<input type=hidden name=UserID value=jsmith /> <input type=hidden name=Role value=Admin />`), and of course, can always validate the user in the Controller that the `edit` action posts to, but, I'd like to know if there is a way to *ON THE CLIENT* verify that the hidden field hasnt been tampered with so that someone doesn't save the file offline, change the hidden field for `Role` and then now they can see the `edit` links when they are not supposed to.

In this contrived example, not much harm comes from being able to see the `edit` links if they cannot do anything, but there are some calls where I pass the role to an API call and it returns data that is flagged as "private" in the database that shouldn't be seen without the correct privileges.

So, basically, the question becomes "is there any way to exchange data between the ASPX page and the JavaScript that then calls the API without it being just stored in a hidden field that could be tampered with?"

Thanks,

Comment: the question too long. you probably want to shorten it and keep it to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not pass the role as a parameter of an ajax call.

The action method itself should determine the role of the user.

Comment: Good point.  I guess I should write the API so that some userID or authentication token is sent with each request.  Appreciate the straightforward answer.

Comment: I think you dont need to send it. The ajax request should contain the authentication - cookie by default. You can check that in firebug under network.